# presses not working tvos - swift

Tags: swift, tvos

I am trying to detect presses in swift, and I am unable to detect a press. Here is my code:

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("test1")
}

override func pressesChanged(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("test2")
}

override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("test3")
}

override func pressesCancelled(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("test4")
}
```

After executing the code on a physical apple tv and on a simulator, the console remains empty. Why are presses not being detected? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, but I am not sure why the override method didn't work.

```
let press:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressed))
press.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.select.rawValue)]
view.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

Comment: It depends on where your previous code was written: the press methods are only called on objects that are in the responder chain between the focused item and the window.

Comment: The override functions where in a SKScene class